# Getting error in Go when using same Type declaration in two files

Tags: go, pointers

I'm trying to write a lambda function in Go.
My `main.go`:

```golang
package main
    
import (
    "context"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/<username>/<project>/utils"
)

type Response events.APIGatewayProxyResponse


func Handler(ctx context.Context) (Response, error) {


    return utils.StandardResponse("Successfully executed the create handler function", http.StatusOK), nil

}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handler)
}
```

And `utils/responses.go` is :

```golang
package utils

import (

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
)

type Response events.APIGatewayProxyResponse

func StandardResponse(body string, statusCode int) Response {
    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        StatusCode: statusCode,
        Body:       string(body),
        Headers: map[string]string{
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        },
    }
}
```

When I try to build the project, I get the following error :

```
# command-line-arguments
handlers/handler1/main.go:31:31: cannot use utils.StandardResponse("Successfully executed the create handler function", http.StatusOK) (type utils.Response) as type Response in return argument
```

However, this error goes away if I stop using **type Response events.APIGatewayProxyResponse** and instead replace `Response` with `events.APIGatewayProxyResponse`, everything builds with no error.

I'm not sure why this is happening. Can I not use the same type in different files?

Comment: They are not the same type: "A defined type is always different from any other type." https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining `Response` twice (once in `main.go` and once in `utils/responses.go`), use `utils.Response` in your `main.go` code:

```golang
func Handler(ctx context.Context) (utils.Response, error) {
...
}
```